# Split datetime on the UI

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

In my ASP.NET MVC app, I have a ViewModel property called "Date" which is of the format "5/18/2012 2:43:45 PM". I would like to split this into separate controls on the UI.

```
jQuery UI - Datepicker would show the date - DONE
Show three dropdowns next to the Datepicker that display hour,minutes and am/pm.
```

I've added the three dropdowns to the UI but I am having difficulty understanding how to set those values based on what is being returned by the "Date" property of the ViewModel? In other words how do I split the Date and display it on the three dropdowns?

EDIT: Here is the View:

```
<div>           
            <%= Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.Scheduled, new { @Value = Model.Scheduled.Value.ToShortDateString(), @class = "datetime", style = "width:150px;" })%>                                      
                   <ol class="align">
                <li class="align" >
                    <select name="hour" >
                        <option value="1">1 </option>
                        <option value="2">2 </option>
                        <option value="3">3 </option>
                        <option value="4">4 </option>
                        <option value="5">5 </option>
                        <option value="6" >6 </option>
                        <option value="7">7 </option>
                        <option value="8">8 </option>
                        <option value="9">9 </option>
                        <option value="10">10 </option>
                        <option value="11">11 </option>
                        <option value="12">12 </option>                       
                    </select></li>                  
            </ol>        
            </div>
```

Comment: Is this homework?  If so, please tag appropriately.

Comment: no - this is not a homework. I was hoping to get some suggestions on how to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

If the "Date" property is of the correct type (DateTime) you should be able to call Date.Hour, Date.Minute, and use Date.ToString("tt") to get am/pm.

Assuming MVC3 with razor....

```
<div id="time">
    Hour:<br/>
    <input type="text" value="@Model.Date.Hour" /><br/>
    Minute:<br/>
    <input type="text" value="@Model.Date.Minute" /><br/>
    AM/PM:<br/>
    <input type="text" value="@Model.Date.ToString("tt").ToLower()" />
</div>
```

Comment: yes. the Date property is DateTime. But if I use the above code the value that is displayed on the UI is "@Model.Date.Hour". If I remove the quotes I get an error "Attribute values must be enclosed in quotes"

Comment: What version of MVC are you using? Also, are you using the Razor view engine (.cshtml files) or WebForms (.aspx)? If you are using webforms that could be the issue. Can you post the code from your view in your question?

Comment: I am using .aspx. Updated the Q with the View. Thanks.